# chmod while svn updating

Tags: svn, chmod

I am "svn updating" my project but it is taking a while (hours). 
Meanwhile I want to "chmod -R 777" a folder inside my project (where I am svn updating).
Do you know if this will break the svn update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it'll be fine - as long as you don't remove permissions so svn can't modify the files, you'll be ok.